# Simple calculation program in assembly MASM

Tags: beginner, integer, assembly

I am a beginner in assembly. This program calculates:

`(Z+Z)+(X-Y)`

```
DATA_SEG    SEGMENT     
      X     DW 2            
      Y     DW 3 
      Z     DW 5 
      RES1  DW ?
      RES2      DW ?               
 DATA_SEG        ENDS    
 CODE_SEG        SEGMENT            

           ASSUME CS:CODE_SEG, DS:DATA_SEG 

;********************************************** 
 MAIN    PROC    FAR          ;MAIN PROGRAM STARTS HERE.       

        MOV     AX,DATA_SEG           
            MOV     DS,AX      ;INITIALIZING THE DS REGISTER.       

            ; ***FIRST WE CALCULATE (Z+Z) AND SAVE IN RES1****
            MOV     AX,Z     ;              
            add     AX,Z     ;  AX = Z+Z        
            MOV     RES1,AX  ;  HOLD TEMPORARILY THE RESULT OF (Z-Z) IN RES1            

        ; ***SECOND WE CALCULATE  (Y-X) AND SAVE IN RES2***
        MOV     AX,Y     ;  NOW STORE VAR Y IN AX REGISTER
        SUB     AX,X     ;  PERFORM  AX = Y-X
            MOV     RES2,AX  ;  HOLD TEMPORARILY THE RESULT OF (Y-X) IN RES2

            ; ***NOW ADD BOTH RES1 + RES2***

            MOV     AX,RES1  ; STORE  RESULT OF (Z+Z) IN AX REGISTER
            ADD     AX,RES2  ;  ADD RES1 + RES2 

        ;****NOW FOR PRINTING WE MOVE THE VALUE IN DX REGISTER****  

        MOV     DX,AX    ; tO PRINT WE FIRST MOVE DATA IN DX REGISTER    
        ADD     DX,30H ;CONVERT TO ACSII CODE       
            MOV     AH,2        
            INT     21H               
        MOV     AH,04CH   
            INT     21H  
MAIN    ENDP
CODE_SEG        ENDS  
END     MAIN
```

Comment: If you're calculating `(Z-Z)+(X-Y)` why bother with `Z`?  It's always going to be simply `X-Y`, right?

Comment: Ok you are right but this program as a practice not for real calculating.
i want to know is this my solution is correct?

Comment: basically above program is my lab assignment for practice.How to use multiple vars in assembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have some suggestions that may help you improve your code.

### Fix formatting

There seem to be varying numbers of leading spaces on each line, impeding easy reading.  Typically labels and directives start in column 1 and instructions start in column 9 (one tabstop) and are all aligned there.  Many, including me, additionally align comments as well.

### Make comments more useful

Comments like this are useful because they explain *why* we're doing something.

```
MOV     DX,AX    ; tO PRINT WE FIRST MOVE DATA IN DX REGISTER
```

Although it would be easier to read if it wasn't in ALL CAPS.  Other comments are not useful because they explain something obvious from the instruction:

```
 MAIN    PROC    FAR          ;MAIN PROGRAM STARTS HERE.       
    ;  other code
    MOV     DS,AX      ;INITIALIZING THE DS REGISTER.
```

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

There are a few numbers in the code, such as `30H` and `2` that have a specific meaning in their particular context.  By using named constants such as `ASCII_ZERO` or `PRINT_CHAR`, the program becomes easier to read and maintain.

### Think carefully about the problem

As mentioned in a comment, if you're really calculating `(Z-Z)+(X-Y)` then you can simply ignore `Z` because `(Z-Z)` is always going to be zero.  Next, the description says `X-Y` but the code says `Y-X`.  It's usually essential to clearly understand the problem at hand before beginning to write the code.

### Prefer registers to memory

Register use is typically much faster than memory use.  For that reason, I'd recommend eliminating memory use that isn't needed.  In particular, `RES1` and `RES2` could easily be eliminated by either chaining operations or storing temporary values in a register.  By "chaining operations" I mean that `(Z-Z)+(Y-X)` is equivalent to `Z-Z+Y-X` (or simply `Y-X`) so one could simply evaluate the expression from left to right.

### Use the appropriate OS service

The INT 21h, AH=02h is the "Write character to standard output" service, so it's only going to print a single character.  That's fine if you're only ever going to have a single digit non-negative result, but that doesn't seem assured here.  Better would be to create a function that converts the numeric result in AX to a string in memory and then use a function such as INT 21h, AH=40h, "Write to file or device" for output.

### Set all appropriate registers for use by the OS services

The program exits with a call to the DOS "Terminate with error code" function (INT 21h, AH=4Ch) but fails to actually set the error code in AL.

Comment: Only wanted to fix a single typo! Had to include some extra text due to a 6-character submit threshold.